# Unable to find a solution to implement Blazor virtualize for scrolling bottom up

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I have been working on a project on Blazor Server. I have got struck on a chat-box feature in my application which I need to be implement with Lazy-Loading by using the virtualize component.
I have used virtualize for my tables using ItemsProvider action but not finding an accurate way to do so for a chat-box, which need to be scrolled from bottom to upwards, as it is a standard for a chat-box functionality.

Can I get some help regarding my problem?

Comment: Do you really need to virtualize a chat box?  How many rows of data are you expecting to have in memory at a given time?  What, exactly, are you trying to achieve right now?

Comment: I want create a chat box like Facebook which has hundreds of messages but it doesn't load them at once. It only loads a few according to the box size. 
Let's say I have 500 messages for an average chat, then what approach should I use so that it doesn't affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm still unclear what you are trying to do, and what the problem is.  Let's start with something very basic, and you can explain what else you want to do:

```
@page "/virt"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization

<input style="width:500px;" @bind="NewMessage" @onkeyup="UpdateQuestionText" />
<div style="height:500px;overflow-y:scroll; background-color:white; border: 1px solid black; display:flex">
    <div style="align-self:flex-start">
        <Virtualize Items="@Messages" Context="message">
            <div>@message</div>
        </Virtualize>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    List<string> Messages { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    string NewMessage { get; set; } = "";

    public async Task UpdateQuestionText(KeyboardEventArgs e) // Only keyup will actually return the updated value for the input text.
    {
        if (e.Code == "Enter")
        {
            Messages.Insert(0,NewMessage);
            NewMessage = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. But the problem is is a bit tricky. Let's say the messages list is sorted in the ascending order of their creation dates and their count would have been approx 500 in the database (history) per chat. Now whenever someone, let's say person A wants to send a message, he will open the chat box for person B, now there will be some latest messages there, as a standard the chat box scroll always at the end of the container, now if the person A wants to view the history messages he needs to scroll up and as far as he scroll some new messages load and adds up the list.

Comment: The problem with virtualize (or in my understanding) is that it's loads the new rows from the database whenever it scrolls down by using ItemsProvider action which gives the position and number of required rows to be loaded at the runtime. This helps in implementing the lazy loading concept for the data and improves the performance. So basically I want here some kind of logic that will be implemented to the virtualize to load the data in the opposite way means from the latest/bottom to the oldest/up. It there any possible way to achieve that using virtualize ? Or I have to use any other logic?

Comment: Well, I just showed that, didn't I?  By inserting new records at the start of a list, and then virtualizing the list, they will be displayed in reverse order.  Your problem is how to know when there are new records, so that you can update the list in your Virtualize control.  For that, I would think that a singlet service would be the best way to do that.